# How can I change the information from my window in QT after clicking a push button

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton

I want to have two buttons PREVIOUS and NEXT and I would like to have the same window but every time the NEXT button is clicked I want the information to be changed and something new to appear.

How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well in order to help what do you want to be changing? Text labels, input fields,buttons?

Please tell what do you want to change to make you a sample...

Comment: Armando, I want to have a window and some information in it, for example a quiz or a image gallery... Every time I click the push Botton I want the next image to appear ... Is that possible in the same window?

Comment: Hi sorry for not replying before....Ive been very busy this days...Well here you go...I made a small sample for you...hope it helps in someway....Let me know if you need anything else [Download File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzkztd4jpc55io4/ImageTestingProject.rar?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

You should write 2 slot functions and connect with buttons. For example slotPrevious() and slotNext() and connect them with `connect(ui->pushButtonNext, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(slotNext()));`. And update your information widget with these functions.